# Deploying issue with SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to deploy a report with SQL Server 2014, through Visual Studio 2013. The report is building well, it is deploying well, I can see it on my web page but when I click on it, I have the following error

> Impossible de terminer l'action en cours. Les informations d'identification de la source de données de l'utilisateur ne répondent pas à la configuration requise pour exécuter ce rapport ou dataset partagé. Elles ne sont pas stockées dans la base de données du serveur de rapports ou la source de données de l'utilisateur est configurée pour ne pas exiger d'informations d'identification, mais le compte d'exécution sans assistance n'est pas spécifié. (**rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting**)

It means the user data identification does not match or answer, the required config to run this report.

I've configured my datasource with an odbc and I've put the following string within the datasource:

```
Dsn=SQLPOITTOWN;uid=sa;persist security info=False
```

For my credentials, I've put "Use this username and password" with the username `sa`. I let the password field empty as there is no password.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please be aware that questions need to be in **English**. Please translate your error as best as you can.

Comment: Hi @TT. , everything has been provided ;)

Comment: Your connection string doens't have a password entry (even though it is empty). Try adding it.

Comment: @TT. : I tried but to no avail

Comment: Then is undoubtedly a rights problem as I gather from the (translated) error message. Also, it is a bad idea to use the `sa` user and even more of a bad idea to not have a password on any user.

Comment: @TT. : I know for the basic lack of security. Let me create a user and see how it goes. Thanks for your insights

Comment: Be sure to give that user the rights to execute the report.

Comment: @TT. you nailed it correctly. It was a right permission. Thanks. Thinking about it now , should I let the post open for anyone who will have the issue , later on or delete it?

Comment: Hi @marc_s , love your amendment. Thanks.

Comment: Leave it open, you never know who it is going to help. Glad you have your problem solved. GL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To spare you all the comments , the solution is to create a user in the db with a password (see below).

```
Dsn=SQLPOITTOWN;uid=POITTOWNReport;Pwd=Xb521Aabc;persist security info=False
```

The report is appearing correctly.

Thanks @TT. for his valuable help